# Allow videos on s3 bucket to be loaded only from a particular URL

Tags: amazon-s3

My requirement is to be able to load videos via https only from a particular URL (e.g. "https://www.app.myurl.com").

Is that possible?

If yes how?

Here is what I tried.

1) Place video on S3 Bucket.
And setup the guideline.

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": "https://app.sampleurl.at/*"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

It doesn't seem to to what I want. All I can do is change the ACL on file level to either be accessible for everyone or for none.

Comment: Bear in mind that the Referer is whatever the user agent chooses to send in the request. There's nothing to prevent dishonest UAs from using any Referer value they like.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I will be aware of that.